# Informative exit on stack overflow in worker thread

Tags: c++, linux, windows, multithreading, stack-overflow

I'm writing a C++ program which is going to run a bunch of worker threads on recursive data, such that even though I've increased the default stack space, it's possible that a thread might hit a stack overflow.

The ideal would be to have the stack dynamically expand as needed, but if that's not possible, it's acceptable to have the program fail, and for the user to retry after recompiling it with a larger stack size.

The problem with the default behavior of the program crashing with no error message is that the user has no way of knowing what the problem was or what to do about it; for all the user knows, the program might have tried to divide by zero or dereference a null pointer; so if the program must crash, I'd like it to print "Stack overflow" to stderr first.

Obviously there isn't going to be a solution in portable C++ but I would be happy with one solution that works on Windows and another that works on Linux.

Looking at ways to have the program exit with an informative error message on Windows, I've been reading the documentation on vectored and structured exception handling; one problem is that these seem to be local to a thread, and a thread can't safely write to stderr; at best you get a race condition.

Is there a known method of dealing with this?

Comment: I think you may be trying to solve this the wrong way. If it is possible, nay frequent, that your recursive algorithm overflows the stack then you should be re-writing it to be iterative instead.

Comment: @sjdowling Well, it's not frequent, not since I bumped up the stack size; and the data is inherently recursive. Avoiding use of the machine stack would just mean I'd be re-implementing recursion myself, which would be slower as well as making a pig's ear of the code.

Comment: But if you implement the recursion yourself you can be sure to fail gracefully when you run out of space for it.  Also, you won't fail as quickly, because the storage doesn't need to be contiguous.

Comment: @HarryJohnston True. Still, the code is both speed-critical (the reason for wanting multiple threads in the first place) and tricky and hard to get right as it stands. I'd be willing to see just how high I can crank the stack size before things start breaking, first.

Comment: And yes, that's some of the documentation I was looking at for how things work on Windows - I'm not quite clear whether structured or vectored exceptions would be better for this case. There's still the multithreading aspect of things to deal with, though.

Comment: [I deleted my last comment after noticing you'd already mentioned SEH in your question.]  Anyway, SEH should solve your problem, you just have to implement it properly.  Having caught the (structured) exception in your thread, add a message to a thread-safe queue and/or exit the thread with a distinctive error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS (Linux or Unix flavours at least) allow you to catch stack faults.

Something like this:

```
 // Note: Calling printf here is probably not a brilliant idea, 
 // as we're in a signal handler. It is NOT well-defined what happens.
 void handler(int arg)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "Crashed due to signal handler\n"); 
    exit(42);
 }
```

Then in main or some such ...

```
 struct sigaction sa = { handler, NULL, 0, 0, NULL };
 struct sigaction oldsa;
 sigaction(SIGSTKFLT, sa, oldsa);
```

I will try to come up with a bit more of a "complete" solution, with some experiments in a bit.

(I believe it is possible to replace the stack, but I don't think you can, in a meaningful way, actually continue at that point, just allows you to recover in a more sane way than simply crashing!)

This APPEARS to work:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void handler(int arg)
{
    write(2, "stack overflow\n", 15);
    _exit(42);
}

void* duh(void *arg)
{
    if(duh(arg))
    {
        return duh(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        return duh(arg);
    }
}

void* crash_wrapper(void *arg)
{
    static char stack[SIGSTKSZ];
    stack_t ss = {};
    ss.ss_sp = stack;
    ss.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
    sigaltstack(&ss, 0);

    struct sigaction sa = {};
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK,
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, 0);

    return duh(arg);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t;
    int status = pthread_create(&t, 0, crash_wrapper, 0 );

    for(;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Still going..." << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely happy with the `write` inside the handler, but all other methods that I tried didn't seem to work either... :(

Comment: Right, that's a start, though as you say, calling printf from a signal handler is problematic. Hmm, thinking about it, would it be safe to instead `write(2, "stack overflow", 14)`?

Comment: Probably not that much better, really. I'm having a look at something else, which I think will work.

Comment: Could the signal handler add a message to a thread-safe queue, for the main thread to detect and respond to?